# SQL Server 2008 Native Client issue

Tags: sql, sybase, sql-server-native-client

We have two virtual machines on a server. We have Sql server installed on one vm and on another vm sybase is installed. We can't find "SQL Server 2008 Native Client" driver on the machine where we have intalled sybase. We have tried to install it using "sqlncli.msi"  but could not install it. We have got the following error during installation.

> An error occured during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,version="8.0.50727.1833",type="win32",publickeyToken="1fc8b3b9a18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86". Please refer to help Help and Support for more infoemation.HRESULT:0x8007054F.

Can you please help us to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the SQL Server install media, options exist there to install the relevant drivers - and Management Studio to boot to test.